# update single item view in listview scroll issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

A little difficult problem to describe so please be patient

i have a progress bar in every listitem of listview used to show downloading
now to update a single view i get view object of single item
now this view is passed to async task to update only that view for which downloading is in progress

it works fine untill i scroll listview
when i scroll list view progress bar is shown for some random listitem of listview

**code to invoke asynctask**

```
 ListView lv = getListView();
 int visiblePosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
 View v = lv.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
 v.setClickable(true);
 task = new TestLoadingTask();
 task.v = lv.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
 executeAsyncTask(task, null, null, null);
```

**on progressupdate of async task**

```
            @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progress[currentposition] = (Integer)values[0];
        max[currentposition] = 100;
        updateprogress(currentposition,v);
    }


    public void updateprogress(int position,View v)
  {

    ProgressBar update = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.downloadbar);
    if(max!=null && max[position]!=0)
        update.setMax(max[position]);
    if(progress!=null)
        update.setProgress(progress[position]);
    TextView tv_per = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percentage);
    if(progress[position]==max[position])
    {
        tv_per.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        update.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        tv_per.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_per.setText(progress[position]+"/"+max[position]);
        update.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

any reference/advice/example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the sources code of your adapter.

Comment: This approach seems to interfere with the way ListView works. It recycles its elements, so that only a few are used. As a result, lv.getChildAt() will give you whatever it takes from the adapter - a random element. If you really need the progress indicator there, you may want to cache it and provide a view with it in the adapter's getView().

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I understood you right, your problem is that ListView's adapter doesn't create new list-items every time you scroll it, it just converts previous. So if it doesn't have special directions about some views of new visible list-item, it will draw them like in previous list-item which was at this position. 
The solution is to add some flag to your list-items (like boolean isUpdating) and show progress bar at your adapter's getView method if it's true, and hide progress bar otherwise